# Cordova 5.0 default plugin documentation

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-5.0.0

I have started working on Cordova 5.0. Installed default plugins for my new project, but I could not find the documentation for these plugins.
From NPM, "[Sadly, this package has no readme.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-camera)" for the default plugins. Can anyone suggest where to find the documents other than finding APIs from the plugins' js files?

[image: No docs on npmjs.com]

Comment: what s the difference for plugreg.com from http://plugins.cordova.io/#/ and npm register? Since the plugins now installed from npm.

Comment: you find complete descriptions. plugins will be downloaded from npm only

Comment: There is a bug with the NPM plugins, they are working on it

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/) out.
You have normally all shared-existent plugins.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=ecosystem%3Acordova (Cordova core plugins on npm)

https://github.com/apache?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=cordova (Cordova core plugin instruction pages)